# Triangle with specific angle

Tags: css, angle

I want to set a triangle's angle only with css to 26°.

```
section#hero .triangle{
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-left: 100px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 800px solid transparent; 

border-right:200px solid #d6d6d6; 

position: absolute;
right: 0;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: This cannot be done with CSS alone. Using `border-bottom` as `800px`, we know that `border-left` should be `390px` if you want an angle of 26deg. You'll have to use javascript or LESS if you want to dynamically change it.

Comment: @jaunt it worked, thanks a lot